# Convert the string into special string

Tags: c, string

Input:
Hello There

Output:

Olleh Ereht

Input:

How are you?

output:

Woh Era ?you

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char s[100], r[100];
   int n, c, d=0;
   int p=0,t=0;

   printf("Input a string\n");
   gets(s);

   //n = strlen(s);

    while(s[p]!= '\0'){
        while(s[p]!= ' ' || s[p]!= '\0'){
            p++;
        }

        for (c = p-1; c >= t; c--, d++)
            r[d] = s[c];

        r[d++] = ' ';

     // printf("%s\n", r);
        t=p;
        p++;
    }

    r[d]= '\0';
    printf("%s\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting Time Limit Exceeded problem..Don't know where i am going wrong.Plz help me with the solution.

Comment: `while(s[p]!= ' ' || s[p]!= '\0')` is wrong. this is infinite loop.

Comment: `Woh Era ?you` typo as `Woh Era ?uoy` ??

Answer (score 1):

I think the inner while loop never terminates because the condition never gives false.
For the loop to terminate:

**s[p] != ' '** and **s[p] != '\0'** both should be false.

That is to say

**s[p]== ' '** and **s[p]== '\0'** both should be true, which is not possible.

That's why you are getting the time limit exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char s[100], r[100];
    int p = 0, d = -1;

    printf("Input a string\n");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", s);//gets(s);<-- "gets" already was obsolete.

    while(1){
        if(s[p] != ' ' && s[p] != '\0'){
            r[++d] = s[p];
        } else {
            if(d >= 0){
                putchar(toupper(r[d--]));
                while(d >= 0){
                    putchar(tolower(r[d--]));
                }
            }
            if(s[p] == ' ')
                putchar(' ');
            else
                break;
        }
        ++p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```